# get user picture together with AppID/score

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

From the Facebook Graph API explorer I'm submitting a Get function for AppID/scores. Apart from user, score and application data, I would like to get user's picture as well. What Graph API query can I submit to achieve this?

Comment: Take a look at the url of your profile picture here on [so] :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply reference the users id in a URL similar to this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/picture
```

Here is a live example:

[image]

That image was rendered with this code:

```
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/4/picture" width="50" />
```

Answer (score 0):

http://graph.facebook.com/XXXXXX/picture
Change XXXXX To the user ID  :)